# Error serializing for view state

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I am having problems serialising data for the view state. I am using VS2010 and when trying to add a property to the view state I get the following error message:

```
Error serializing value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Access.ARW.Business.Filters.Parameters.Parameter]' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Access.ARW.Business.Filters.Parameters.Parameter, Access.ARW.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].'
```

I have added a [Serializable] attribute above the classes I am trying to serialise but I still get this error...any ideas

Here is the property declaration which is in Class A:

```
private List<Filters.Parameters.Parameter> ReportParameters
{
   get
   {
       if (ViewState["ReportParameters"] == null)
       {
           ViewState["ReportParameters"] =
               new List<Filters.Parameters.Parameter>();
       }
       return (List<Filters.Parameters.Parameter>) ViewState["ReportParameters"];
   }

   set
   {
       ViewState["ReportParameters"] = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your class contain further objects? If so everything in your object hierarchy must be marked [Serializable]

Comment: please post the code sample.. it would help out as well as others to understand what your code is doing

Comment: @pjmonks - yes there are several classes that subclass one another - these have all had the [serializable] attribute added to them....

Comment: Please don't add things like " - C# VS2010" to your titles. That's what the tags are for. Also, the question has nothing to do with VS2010.

Comment: Did you try storing a simple array instead of a List ? This shouldn't be a problem though, but I've heard this advice many times.

Answer (score 6):

Did you miss adding the Serializable attribute to one of the components of the class?  Try adding the parts of the class one-by-one to ViewState until you find the one that is wrong.

Comment: Divide and conquer is a fundamental debugging technique.  I don't understand how taking something that is 'huge' and temporarily breaking it into smaller chunks could be a problem.  If it really is that 'huge' then it probably doesn't belong in ViewState anyways.

Comment: How about creating unit tests to ensure your objects are serializable?

Comment: Taking something huge and breaking it apart *can* be a problem if the codebase is huge and unfamiliar, and if your predecessors who maintained said code left it smelly.